# Dataframe iteration to compare rows without for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I'm trying to compare yearly GDP values to locate recessions in my data.

```
    GDP in billions of current dollars  GDP in billions of chained 2009 dollars
Quarterly (Seasonally adjusted annual rates)        
1947q1  243.1   1934.5
1947q2  246.3   1932.3
1947q3  250.1   1930.3
1947q4  260.3   1960.7
1948q1  266.2   1989.5
```

Here's the .head() of my data. I'm comparing the rows of 'GDP in billions of chained 2009 dollars' to find quarters with negative growth

At the moment I've iterated through the column and created a list to append later. I realise is probably a poor method of doing this and I was wondering if anyone could help me improve my code:

```
mask = []
for i in range(0,len(df)):
    try:
        if df.ix[i,2] > df.ix[i-1,2] : mask.append('False')
        else : mask.append('True')
    except:
        mask.append('False')
        continue
```

The code has an issue with entry 1 as it has nothing to compare it with (hence the guardian code) for a start, not a big worry as we can tell it to start 'False'

I can append the list to the dataframe and continue, but I'm learning Pandas at the moment and would like to do this properly using vectorization if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you can use vectorized [Series.diff()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html) method:

```
In [86]: df.iloc[:, 2].diff().lt(0)
Out[86]:
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
Name: c, dtype: bool
```

if you need a Vanilla Python list:

```
In [93]: df.iloc[:, 2].diff().lt(0).tolist()
Out[93]: [False, True, True, False, False]
```

---

Source DF:

```
In [87]: df
Out[87]:
        a      b       c
0  1947q1  243.1  1934.5
1  1947q2  246.3  1932.3
2  1947q3  250.1  1930.3
3  1947q4  260.3  1960.7
4  1948q1  266.2  1989.5
```

difference

```
In [88]: df['c'].diff()
Out[88]:
0     NaN
1    -2.2
2    -2.0
3    30.4
4    28.8
Name: c, dtype: float64
```

Comment: That's worked great, thank you. I'm not really sure what the .lt(0) does though - mark negative values as True and positive as False?

Comment: @LeonKyriacou, glad i could help :-)

Comment: @MaxU - really nice vectorized solution ;)